# Interpolation C# in foreach loop, how to do that

Tags: c#, arrays, string-interpolation

I have following code in my programm:

```
        string[] strarray = new string[] {bird, lion, ape};
        Array.Reverse(strarray);

        strarray.Reverse();
        foreach(var value in strarray)
        {

           Console.Write(value.ToString());

        }
```

I want the Array "strarray" to be surrounded like that Array[ strarray ]. I cant use the string.Format here because it loops through it and with each string the text Array[ ... ] gets added. How should I do here?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do. Please post the attempt so we can understand better

Comment: "I want the Array "strarray" to be surrounded like that Array[ strarray ]" > what does this mean? string interpolation is just a syntactic sugar for `string.Format`. you need to elaborate your question.

Comment: The result of Console.Write(value.ToString()); is ape, lion, bird. And I want that Array[ape, lion, bird] to be displayed. And I do not know how I should add the text Array [] in which the result should be in and not only ape, lion, bird on the display

Comment: To understand my problem : If I use the string.Format like that  Console.Write(string.Format("Array[{0}]", value.ToString()));  I get the result: Array[bird]Array[lion]Array[ape] because of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string[] strarray = new string[] { "bird", "lion", "ape" };

Console.Write($"Array[{String.Join(", ", strarray.Reverse())}]");
```

That gives me:

```
Array[ape, lion, bird]
```